# How do I tell GNU make to remove intermediate files right away?

Tags: makefile

I'm using make to automate the creation of a file which depends on several other files, each of which depends on an intermediate file being created, and ultimately on a file on the hard drive.

```
    all
   /   \
 a1     a2
  |      |
 b1     b2
  |      |
file1  file2
```

`all` depends on `a1` and `a2`, which depend on the intermediate files `b1` and `b2`, which are in turn made from `file1` and `file2` on the hard drive. Here's my Makefile.

```
all: $(patsubst %, a%, 1 2)
    echo "making all"

a%: b%
    echo "making $@ from $^"

b%: file%
    echo "making $@ from $^"
```

When I do `make -n`, I see the following output (after touching `file1` and `file2`).

```
echo "making b1 from file1"
echo "making a1 from b1"
echo "making b2 from file2"
echo "making a2 from b2"
echo "making all"
rm b1 b2
```

My problem is that `b1` and `b2` are extremely large, and I can't keep them both on my hard drive at the same time (in my real situation, it's not just two but dozens of these files). Is there a way to tell make to dispose of `b1` as soon as `a1` is finished, before starting to make `a2`? In other words, I would like to see the following output.

```
echo "making b1 from file1"
echo "making a1 from b1"
rm b1
echo "making b2 from file2"
echo "making a2 from b2"
rm b2
echo "making all"
```

Comment: You can't.  You can delete the files yourself, though, by explicitly putting the `rm` command in the recipe for `a1` and `a2`.

Comment: *facepalm* yeah I guess that's the obvious solution, thanks.